# syncfusion autocomplete textbox not working with jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, syncfusion

I am using a syncfusion autocomplete texbox inside a jquery dialog. In mvc3 entity framework. But i am not getting any value in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred because the z-index value of the AutoComplete suggestion list is set as 1 by default whereas jquery dialog control has highest z-index(default 1000) , so the suggestion list pops out behind the dialog control .

Please use the below CSS overriding for configure the z-index value to resolve the issue.

```
 
   .Autocomplete_SuggestionList
     {
         z-index:2000 !important;
     }
```